# Using json vs string values in Redis

Tags: redis, node-redis, redis-stack-server

I'm evaluating redis to understand between json vs string what provides better retrieval performance. As POC I set below json in redis as both json and string values and noticed that the size of JSON value is more than String - please see attached screen shots.

json value size = 239B
string value size = 136B
For this POC I used redis-stack-server on my mac.

Based on what I noticed, I have three questions.

- Why size of JSON value is more than String
- Why retrieval of JSON values is slower than String
- What is the best alternate to Redis that could provide me better performance as caching layer for APIs

```
{key:"HbaJsv"location:339secret:"nD9pVeqZIxAIPsY"delta:6}
```

[String values screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFC9u.png)

[Json values screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orV5f.png)

This is a sample of the code I used.

```
import redis

client = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6677)
doc = {key:"HbaJsv"location:339secret:"nD9pVeqZIxAIPsY"delta:6}
client.json().set("some_hash1", '$', doc)
client.set("some_hash2", json.dumps(doc))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you'd only like to retrieve JSONs by their key - you can use Strings.

But on [Redis Stack](https://redis.io/docs/about/about-stack/) you can also execute [JSONpath queries](https://redis.io/commands/json.get/) over JSON documents, as well as [index](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/indexing/) and [query](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/query/) JSON documents.

Of course, to support such operations, Redis stores JSON documents differently than simple strings.